# Volume specification error, docker-compose up

Tags: windows, docker, path, docker-compose

My code builds alright but when I run `docker-compose up` I get this error.

```
Creating app_webapp_1 ... error

ERROR: for app_webapp_1  Cannot create container for service webapp: invalid volume specification: 'C:\Users\Me\Path\App\Front:./dFront:rw'

ERROR: for webapp  Cannot create container for service webapp: invalid volume specification: 'C:\Users\Me\Path\App\Front:./dFront:rw'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

### Config

- Windows 10 latest version of everything (stable)
- Windows container (I can't switch to linux ones for memory reason)

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  webapp:
    build: ./Front
    volumes:
      - ./Front:./dFront
    ports:
      - 5001:8080
```

#### What I already tried (and did not work)

- `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=0`
- `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1`
- Abosute path: `- ./Front:C:/Users/Me/Path/App/Front`

The latest lead to a different error though:

```
ERROR: for app_webapp_1  Cannot start service webapp: container d36a23d8e44193a16734d8c12f0cab4cc13d7d492671081d8b016795b1f79f8c encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) extra info: {"CommandLine":"npm start","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\dFront","Environment":{"NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL":"info"},"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}
```